# Is there an open source .NET Message Bus for Windows App to Service App?

Tags: vb.net

I have a Windows Application (GUI updates database which service uses, GUI gets information from service) and a Windows Service (Does the gruntwork).  Both projects are vb.net.  I would like to be able to pass information back and forth in a message bus style.. The following are the types of information transfers I would have at minimum:

- Statuses - i.e., Service sends several system statuses for the Windows Application to display on a sort of 'Digital Dashboard' Main dislplay
- Metrics - i.e., Service sends several metrics (failure counts, success counts, and others)
- Configuration Reload - The Windows Application would send a command to reload the configuration settings to the service (that way the service doesn't have to continuously query the database for settings.
- allow for cross computer information transfer, if possible (i.e., using TCP Ports or whatever methodology allows for this)

Simplicity would help :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A "bus" is off the table when you need to interop between two separate processes.  WCF is the common solution.

Comment: Are you thinking guaranteed (eventual) delivery, like with MSMQ or by subscription like with UDP?

Comment: I'm thinking subscribing to the bus, grabbing the messages.

Comment: ok, so if I go with WCF - can I roll my current service into a WCF Service or do I have to have a separate WCF service layer to go between my current service and windows application?  Probably a stupid question :(

Answer (score 0):

[ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) will do this - written in C for low-level network performance, it has C# bindings (and every [example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cs%3ahwclient) has code for all the languages it supports, that's pretty cool).